How do I run NW.JS 20 or newer on a Raspberry Pi 5?
I recently bought a raspberry pi 5 and I want to run nwjs on it but the rpi port of nwjs is so old and didn't have rpi 5 on the compability list.. there is any way to install nwjs on rpi? Without bugs

I still didn't try any version of nwjs on raspberry pi and I expect to work properly


https://onexception.dev/news/1391071/running-nw-js-on-raspberry-pi-5
